# How to set .AspNetCore.Identity.Application Cookies expiration based on Identity Claims Role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm looking to set the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` Cookie's expiration time based on the role of claims of a user that logs in.

In all of the configure options in `ConfigureServices` I have access to cookie properties but no access to user claims. Therefore I cannot dynamically set the expiration time. We are using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity SignInManager` to authenticate.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what class I need to override or what middleware I need to register to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The Cookie Authentication Handler will trigger `OnSigningIn` event before generating an authentication ticket, see source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L292) :

```
protected async override Task HandleSignInAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthenticationProperties properties)
{
    // ...
    if (!signInContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc.HasValue)
    {
        signInContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc = issuedUtc.Add(Options.ExpireTimeSpan);
    }

    await Events.SigningIn(signInContext);

    if (signInContext.Properties.IsPersistent)
    {
        var expiresUtc = signInContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc ?? issuedUtc.Add(Options.ExpireTimeSpan);
        signInContext.CookieOptions.Expires = expiresUtc.ToUniversalTime();
    }

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(signInContext.Principal, signInContext.Properties, signInContext.Scheme.Name);
    // ...

}
```

(Note the line `await Events.SigningIn(signInContext);` )

This gives us a chance to modify the expiration time using `Events.OnSigningIn`. So in your `ConfigureServices()` method, add codes as below :

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>{
    opt.Events.OnSigningIn = async(signinContext)=>{

        // you can use the pricipal to query claims and roles as you need
        var x = signinContext.Principal.Claims.First(c=>c.Type=="X1" && ...); 
        // set the expiration time according to claims/roles dynamically 
        signinContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(100);
        signinContext.CookieOptions.Expires = signinContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc?.ToUniversalTime();

    };
});
```

It will work as expected.